# Enviar POST Textarea um valor por linha

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho um `form` com um `textarea` onde terá um valor por linha.
Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso enviar esse valor para o Banco de dados MySQL.

Depois em outra página preciso criar um **For** para listar esses valores.

*O que me traz confusão é que não pode ter nada, como referencia pela quebra de linha..*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O TextArea já quebra o texto com "\n";

```
<?
  $linhas = split("\n", $txtBox);
  foreach($linhas as $linha)
  {
    echo $linha . " <br> ";
  }
?>


<form action="" method="get">
<p>
  <textarea name="txtBox" cols="50" rows="10" id="txtBox"></textarea>

</p>
<label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
   </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Então se eu já fizer o $_POST para o MySQL, já vai com a linha quebrada e depois para fazer o For só usar seu código acima?

Comment: Exatamente. Se você gravar o $_POST direto em um campo text, ou varchar, ao recuperar pode usar o código acima, faz o teste.

Comment: [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) está obsoleta e não deve ser usada em projetos novos, prefira [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 3):

Quando vc recuperar essa informação, tente usar o explode do php para criar um vetor e fazer o for.

> Exemplo

```
<?php

    $retorno_db = $_POST['text_area']; // Aqui coloca o valor do textarea que vai para o banco

    $dados = explode("\n",$retorno_db);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($dados); $i++) {

        $linha = $retorno_db[$i];
        //Cada vez que passar vai ser uma linha... Agora é só usar a lógica.
        echo $linha."<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe o caractere '\n' que delimita a quebra de linha em Javascript...
Tente percorrer o valor do textarea, caractere por caractere... quando achar um '\n' ou o fim da string, você achou o fim de uma linha e pode guarda-la em um array. Veja o exemplo de código:

```
<script>

    var texto = "Texto que \nestará no \ntextarea em várias \nlinhas";

    var linhas = [];
    var linha = ""; 
    for (var i = 0; i < texto.length; i++ ){
       if (texto[i] != '\n') {
          linha += texto[i];
       }

       if (texto[i] == '\n' || i == texto.length - 1) {
          if (linha.length != 0 )
             linhas.push( linha );
          linha = "";
       }       
    }

    //A variável linhas é um vetor contendo cada linha do texto separada
    console.log (linhas);

</script>
```

Comment: Tem que ser PHP.