# consulta de operadoras de celular

Tags: php, html, libcurl

Comecei uma consulta para saber qual é a operadora do celular puxando de um site.
Porém, só consigo fazer uma por vez.
Gostaria de ajuda pra que eu pudesse colar uma lista e ela fosse mandando requisições e imprimindo o resultado separado.

```
<?php
$fone = $_POST['tel_fone']; 
$fone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $fone); function get_operadora($fone){ $url = "http://consultanumero.info/consulta";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://google.com.br/'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "tel=$fone"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$data = curl_exec ($ch); if(preg_match("/(oi)/",$data )){ $resultado = "OI"; } if(preg_match("/(vivo)/",$data )){ $resultado = "VIVO"; } if(preg_match("/(tim)/",$data )){ $resultado = "TIM"; } if(preg_match("/(claro)/",$data )){ $resultado = "CLARO"; } if(preg_match("/(nextel)/",$data )){ $resultado = "NEXTEL"; } return trim($resultado); curl_close ($ch); } 
$operadora = get_operadora($fone);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> O site em questão (`consultanumero.info/consulta`) implementou um ReCaptcha, o que faz o código abaixo não funcionar atualmente.

---

Você pode simplesmente fazer um `foreach` do tipo`

```
$numeros = [
 '11999999999',
 '22988888888',
 '21912345678'
];
```

Depois fazer:

```
foreach($numeros as $numero){

    get_operadora($numero);

}
```

---

Mas tem várias que podem piorar a performance, veja isto:

```
 if (preg_match("/(oi)/", $data)) {
     $resultado = "OI";
 }
 if (preg_match("/(vivo)/", $data)) {
     $resultado = "VIVO";
 }
 if (preg_match("/(tim)/", $data)) {
     $resultado = "TIM";
 }
 if (preg_match("/(claro)/", $data)) {
     $resultado = "CLARO";
 }
 if (preg_match("/(nextel)/", $data)) {
     $resultado = "NEXTEL";
 }
 return trim($resultado);
 curl_close($ch);
```

**"Erros":**

1. Nenhum telefone tem duas operadoras, logo ou é `OI` ou é `VIVO`, o seu código não liga para isto. Se ele encontra `OI` ele ainda irá buscar por `VIVO`, por `TIM`, por `CLARO`... O uso do `elseif` reduziria isto.
2. O `curl_close()` nunca será usado, o `return` está antes dele.

---

Uma melhor opção seria utilizar o `multi_curl` e utilizar o `preg_match`, assim removendo o `if` e o curl será executado mais rápido:

```
function get_operadora(array $telefones){

    $curlIndividual = [];
    $operadora = [];

    $curlTodos = curl_multi_init();

    foreach($telefones as $telefone){

        $curlIndividual[$telefone] = curl_init('https://consultanumero.info/consulta');

        curl_setopt_array($curlIndividual[$telefone], [
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0',
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
            CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS | CURLPROTO_HTTP,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'tel='.$telefone,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
        ]);


        curl_multi_add_handle($curlTodos, $curlIndividual[$telefone]);

    }


    $Executando = 1;

    while($Executando> 0){
        curl_multi_exec($curlTodos, $Executando);
        curl_multi_select($curlTodos);
    }


    foreach($curlIndividual as $telefone => $curl){

        $resultado = curl_multi_getcontent($curl);

        if(preg_match('/<img src="(.*?)" alt="(.*?)" title="(.*?)" \/>/', $resultado, $matches)) {

            $operadora[$telefone] = $matches[2];

        }

    }

    return $operadora;

}
```

Mudanças:

- Somente aceita `array`.
- Verifica o SSL com os certificado que você confia, devido ao `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, *que é recomendado e é padrão do PHP 7.1*.
- Apenas utiliza o HTTP/HTTPS, definido no `CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS`.
- Utiliza o `multi_curl`, definido em `curl_multi_exec`.
- Obtém a operadora baseado no `<img src="(.*?)" alt="(.*?)" title="(.*?)" \/>`,  sem qualquer `if`.

Utilização:

```
$numeros = [
    '11999999999',
    '22988888888',
    '21999991234'
];


get_operadora($numeros);
```

Retorno:

```
array(3) {
  ["11999999999"]=>
  string(4) "Vivo"
  ["22988888888"]=>
  string(2) "Oi"
  ["21999991234"]=>
  string(4) "Vivo"
}
```

> Testado em PHP 7.1, versões antigas podem ter incompatibilidade.

Atenção:

Considere isto como um exemplo, o ideal seria quebrar isto em várias funções e verificar se todas as variáveis estão sendo definidas corretamente.

Comment: No caso eu vou usar form em html pra o $numeros = [
    '11999999999',
    '22988888888',
    '21999991234'
]; porque preciso montar uma lista grande, me ajuda a montar o codigo?

Comment: Pergunte de maneira mais clara, basta criar um `array` com os números, tem várias peguntas sobre isso aqui.

Comment: No caso, eu queria colocar uma lista de numeros em uma textarea e ele ir imprimindo os resultados das operadoras entende pra que eu possa separar tudo

Comment: Veja por `explode`, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70442/15089

Comment: entendi, vou fazer um exemplo aqui, você me ajuda com o codigo inteiro depois que eu montar aqui ?

Comment: olha ai >  https://pastebin.com/EGeC0zQ3

Comment: Defina o `get_operadora()` depois `get_operadora(explode("\n", $_GET['numeros']));`. O `split` está obsoleto e não é suportado em PHP 7+.